# error "IOError: file /.../ does not exist" with sidekiq on public files on rails 6

Tags: heroku, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6, ioerror

I have this error when my worker (using Sidekiq on Heroku) try to read my public files uploaded with Carrierwave gem,

```
2021-02-28T01:55:14.424963+00:00 app[worker.1]: pid=4 tid=gt1kpgehs WARN: IOError: file /app/public/uploads/excel_doc/attachment/240/lista_1.xlsx does not exist
```

Im trying to read the excel files (uploaded) with 'roo' gem

```
doc = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(self.attachment, extension: :xlsx)
```

I already tried to read the file from specific path (where by default is stored, and also moving to tmp folder),

1. `excel_path = "public/uploads/excel_doc/attachment/#{id}/" + attachment.identifier`
2. `excel_path = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/excel_doc/attachment/#{id}/" + attachment.identifier`

but the same error is raised.

Note: In my localhost everything works very good, in production it crash

I think is some bad configuration with the Heroku server, I have this:

[Heroku redis connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ttdv.png)